# Yii2 translating data stored in database

Tags: php, database, internationalization, yii2, language-translation

I'm working with Yii2 Framework, and already configured i18n component using this guide:
http://thecodeninja.net/2014/12/i18n-with-yii-2-advanced-template/

So, I can now translate strings within my php files using `Yii::t()` function. Translatable strings are extracted using `$ ./yii message/extract` console command, which generates proper translation files.

I now need to display translations for strings stored in the database.

I could use `Yii:t()` with a variable instead of a string as an argument like this

```
echo Yii:t('app', $some_string_from_db );
```

and make a new php file with some code like this

```
<?php 

function dbStringsToTranslate() {
    $o = Yii::t('app','db english string 1'); 
    $o.= Yii::t('app','db english string 2'); 
    $o.= Yii::t('app','db english string 3'); 
    return $o;
}
```

This way `$ ./yii message/extract` command will find the needed translations.

This is working Ok, but of course `$ ./yii message/extract` is throwing some warnings anywhere I use `Yii:t()` with variables.

```
Skipping line 39. Make sure both category and message are static strings.
```

I think this is not a big deal, but well, here is my question:

Is this a right way to translate strings stored in a database?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: The thing is, the main focus of i18n on Yii2 is to translate UI text, not to work as a translator for data in your app. I would not recommend using i18n to do so, if there is no 'The Yii2 Way Solution' you can find some other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this extension. https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-translateable it allows for attaching behaviors to models to support multiple languages.

I am using it now in a projects and it is easy to use.

Comment: This seems promising. I've been trying to use this behavior but it's not working as expected. Translation's model validation fails. The key attribute is not being set. I've tried for a new record and for an existing one, and the results are the same. Are you using the extension's current version? I've installed it through composer.

Comment: You can easily fix that by.... wait did you just took your points back... hmm... good luck I guess.

Comment: Actually I did find a workaround for that issue. There are your points back to you. I really appreciate your help, it has been greatly useful. I'm a newbie at stackoverflow and I've just noticed I can improve your answer. I'll do that tomorrow when I have all the info.

Comment: Just make the foreign key not required. That will make it work, it took me some time to figure that easy fix out. I will update the extension to reflect that.

Comment: Great!! that's it! That's way easier than my workaround. I was manually setting that attribute before saving the model. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, and I found the solution with [this module](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager). In the module configuration you have the 'tables' array, in which you can specify which field(s) of which table(s) should be translated. 
Then, the module has its own 'scan' action (equivalent to message/extract) with which it adds all the translatable strings to database (using [DbMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html)): all Yii::t, the specified database fields, and many more (even javascript, check the docs). It also has a nice user interface to do the translations, it's awesome!

For example, with the following configuration the field name from table nationality will be scanned and added for its translation (i.e country names):

```
'modules' => [
'translatemanager' => [
    'class' => 'lajax\translatemanager\Module',
    ...
    'tables' => [                   // Properties of individual tables
        [
            'connection' => 'db',   // connection identifier
            'table' => 'nationality',         // table name
            'columns' => ['name'], // names of multilingual fields
            'category' => 'database-table-name',// the category is the database table name
            'categoryPrefix' => 'lx-'           // 
        ]
    ]
],
```

],

Answer (score 0):

You can generate php file with some fake `Yii:t()` calls.
**For example:**

```
$filename = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/runtime/fake-category-translations.php');
$str = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;
foreach (Category::find()->all() as $category) {
    $str .= "Yii::t('category', '{$category->name}');" . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents($filename, $str);
```

In output this file will be something like this:

```
<?php
Yii::t('category', 'Art & Design');
Yii::t('category', 'Creativity');
Yii::t('category', 'Educational');
Yii::t('category', 'Education');
Yii::t('category', 'Lifestyle');
Yii::t('category', 'Casual');
```

So, now you can just call console method for searching untranslated strings:

```
php yii message/extract @frontend/messages/config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I faced same thing with rest API, and here is how I went about resolving it. Note that When saving I used

```php
$post->comment = Yii::t('app', 'My Nice Comment here');
$post->save();
```

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function fields()
    {
        $fields = parent::fields();
        
        $fields['comment'] = function ($model) {
            return Yii::t('app', $model->comment);
        };

        return $fields;
    }
}
```